# Directive newly created in new scope with $compile does not ng-animate

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, css-transitions, ng-animate, angularjs-compile

I have a `switcher` directive, which has a method that creates a new scope and, using `$compile` on it, replaces its `element` with another directive, the `lister` one.

For example purposes, the `lister` directive contains a ng-repeat that iterates on the new scope.

I tried to animate the newly-created `lister` directive as soon as it is created with `ng-enter` and `ng-leave` classes, but it does not have any effect, or so it seems.

Is it possible to animate a directive dynamically created with `$scompile`? If so, what am I missing?

The code is in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WK0pJSWCBCFMbMUriItv?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is the issue:-

It should be `.list-directive li` since li's are ng-repeated.

```
.list-directive li.ng-enter,
.list-directive li.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.list-directive li.ng-enter {
    margin-left: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.list-directive li.ng-leave,
.list-directive li.ng-enter-active {
    margin-left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
.list-directive li.ng-leave-active {
    margin-left: -200px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ap3mwW?p=preview)**

Or apply a class on the `li's` and apply rules to that. **[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wDqquH?p=preview)**

Comment: This works, but why? If I manually apply the margin-left style to the .list-directive div, it is effectively moved to the right. Why can't I do the same with animations?

Comment: Edited my question, sorry :)

Comment: @janesconference i am sorry i dont understand what your issue is. margin-left is in css animation only right?

Comment: Ok, let's say: what if I wanted to animate the List word before the actual ng-repeat? or if the `lister` directive was really complex and I wanted to animate just the container div to animate everything contained inside?

Comment: @janesconference That is because ng animate applies classes to the items that are part of ng-repeat/ng-show/ng-hide.. etc... WHen you just add something to DOM how can ng repeat animate it unless you toggle some property like ng-show on the container and apply rule to it?

Comment: But I don't want to animate the ng-repeat, I want to animate the whole directive. See this example where the whole include container is animated: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html#animating-nginclude-ngview-and-ngif

Comment: SOmething like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/0YPMST?p=preview or http://plnkr.co/edit/fCMcOt?p=preview

Comment: Like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/9XozqA6Gdq67XsME54c4?p=preview, but now it "stops" for 1 second (the transition time) before animating. Is there a way to animate straight away?